# How to Attach more than one semaphores to Shared memory using shmat?

Tags: c++, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

In Shared Memory, Data can be written anywhere on it by using the pointer attached to it 
For Example if **id** is shared memory id (having size 1024B) and char* type is attached to it as follows

```
char* CharPointertoSm;
CharPointertoSm=(char*)shmat(id, 0, 0);
```

then Data can be read or written anywhere on Shared memory using pointer **CharPointertoSm** 
like, to write on index 10, we do

```
CharPointertoSm[10]='a';
```

My Question is how do we use same scheme to attach more than one semaphores to shared memory? To Attach one semaphore we do

```
sem_t * semDecide = NULL;
if ((semDecide = (sem_t *)shmat(id, 0, 0)) == (sem_t *) -1) 
{
        printf("shmat-sem\r\n");
        shmctl(id,IPC_RMID, 0);            
        exit(1);
}
```

and This semaphore(semDecide) will take first 32 Bytes of shared memory, How can we Assign next 32 bits to another semaphore? because using same as above for another semaphore as

```
sem_t * semDecide2 = NULL;
if ((semDecide2 = (sem_t *)shmat(id, 0, 0)) == (sem_t *) -1) 
{
        printf("shmat-sem\r\n");
        shmctl(id,IPC_RMID, 0);            
        exit(1);
}
```

is not working(maybe because it uses first 32 bytes again, that has previously been assigned to first semaphore(i-e to semDecide)
**How to attach the second semaphore next to first semaphore using shmat?**

Comment: Semaphores are totally independent to shared memory. You may use one to control access to the other. So this line `semDecide2 = (sem_t *)shmat(id, 0, 0))` is wrong. _NB: When using casts be absolutely sure that you need them - usually using them means you are doing something wrong_

Comment: `sem_t *next_semaphore=semDecide2+1`. Now you have another semaphore (which you need to explicitly init, etc...)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sem_t *next_semaphore=semDecide2+1
would not work , it will not be shared among two processes, This semaphore would be local to one process and not shared to second process through shared memory

Comment: I think you're mistaken.